# Catch all exceptions and send them by e-mail

Tags: android, exception

In my app I want to catch all types of exceptions and send reports by e-mail. For that I'm using global try catch block. But now I need to recognize exception by type. How can I do it?

```
try{
...
}
catch (Exception e){
//Here I need to recognize exception by type
send(Error);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why you don't simple send the whole stacktrace?

```
send(e.getStackTrace())
```

It not only contains the Exception type but also where (file, class, line) it occurred.
Additionally, you can also simply use the `toString()` method.

See [the java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#toString%28%29) for further information

Comment: The link has expired.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of rolling your own error logging and reporting mechninism I strongly recommend you use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) Its free, open source, and supports sending error logs to email. I have used it for quite some time and it is very good.

This will give you all sorts of information such as phone make, model, resolution, free memory, as well as a full stack trace of the error. Its by far the easiest way to get quality error reporting into an Android app.

The best part is it takes all of about 5 minutes to get setup and integrated.

Answer (score 1):

```
e.getClass() // will give you Class object

e.getClass().getName() // will give you class name
```

However if you know the class names already you can use

```
if(e instanceof A)
{
    // some processing
}
else if(e instanceof B)
{
    //some processing
}
else
{
    //
}
```

Comment: This is producing unreadable code and i'd say good luck doing this for a hundred exceptions :P

Comment: yes, I agree. it is not best skeleton but if we follow requirement, it fulfils it.